# Android SQLite - How To Update The Record ID Number After Deleting Records

Tags: android, sqlite

I can look up records by values and/or ID
I can add records
I can delete All records
I can delete a specific record (by either value or ID)

But, the record ID only increments - it never adjusts to reflect the number of remaining records after deleting a record.

I haven't found anything on this subject (not even in the Doc's)

What/How do I do this?
Thanks
The declaration for this part of the db follows...

```
    String sql = 
        "create table " 
        + TABLE 
        + "( " + BaseColumns._ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + THE_NUMBER + " integer, "
        + FAV_NAME + " text not null);";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than deleting this post, I'll post the ref to the answer (it's at SQL's site).
[link text](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)